# How can I automatically use curved quotes in text, but straight quotes in HTML tags?

Tags: typography

I have a project, Tufte CSS, that I hand-write in HTML. I want to use smart quotes (aka fancy quotes or curved quotes) in the *text* of that document, but dumb quotes (aka straight quotes) in the *HTML tags* of that document.

How do I achieve this? I currently use web-mode and [typopunct.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/typopunct.el), but the latter automatically inserts smart quotes everywhere, including around HTML attributes, which it thereby causes not to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, this is a solved problem. Typopunct is already able to use curvy quotes in text and straight quotes inside tags for a variety of modes. I happen to edit HTML in a mode typopunct doesn't cover out of the box, but that's no problem. See `typopunct-mode.el`:

```
(defcustom typopunct-mode-exeptions-alist
  '((sgml-mode . typopunct-point-in-xml-tag-p)
    (nxml-mode . typopunct-point-in-xml-tag-p)
    (html-mode . typopunct-point-in-xml-tag-p))
  "Alist for mode specific expections.

This alist specifies major mode specific expectional cases when the
function `typopunct-insert-quotation-mark' should *not* insert
typographical quotation marks.

Each element is a pair of a major mode (a symbol) and a predicate
function that should return non nil, when
`typopunct-insert-quotation-mark' should insert an ASCII `\"'."
  :group 'typopunct
  :type '(alist :key-type symbol :value-type function))
```

Great! Typopunct already has a function to check if it's inside an XML-style angle-bracket tag, and is configured to not insert smart quotes if that's the case while in certain modes.

Instead of html-mode, I use web-mode. So, I added the following to my init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'typopunct-mode-exeptions-alist 
             '(web-mode . typopunct-point-in-xml-tag-p))
```

...and everything is right in the world. Remember, kids: it's just elisp, and most of the time the problem you're having is a problem someone else has had before.

Comment: I'll add a ```web-mode-point-in-xml-tag``` to web-mode.el so that typopunct can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
(defun insert-html-quote ()
  (interactive)

  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion

      (let (backward-nearest-< backward-nearest->)

        (save-excursion
          (search-backward "<")
          (setq backward-nearest-< (point)))

        (save-excursion
          (search-backward ">")
          (setq backward-nearest-> (point)))

        (if (> backward-nearest-< backward-nearest->)
            (insert "\"\"")
          (insert "“”"))))

    (forward-char)))
```

To bind it to quote char of `html-mode-map`:

```
(define-key html-mode-map (kbd "\"") 'insert-html-quote)
```

Comment: Even after I switched the define-key to `web-mode-map` I can't get this to work...I think I need to get deeper into the innards of typopunct.